# Question regarding properties of map which produces measures that are invariant to orthogonal rotation

Tags: pr.probability, invariant-theory, orthogonal-groups

Let $\mathcal{M}_1$ denote the set of probability measures on the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^d$ (which comes with its Borel $\sigma$-field). Denote by $\sigma$ the uniform measure on the orthogonal group O(d).

Consider the operator $\mathcal{M}_1 \to \mathcal{M}_1$ which takes a measure $\pi \in \mathcal{M}_1$ to $\overline{\pi}$, which satisfies
$$
\overline \pi (E) = \int_{O(d)} \pi(QE) \, \mathrm{d} \sigma(Q),
$$
for any measurable subset $E$ of the unit ball. Note that we define  $QE = \{Q x: x\in E\}$. Clearly the mapping $\pi \mapsto \overline \pi$ produces $O(d)$-invariant measures.

Is this mapping well known? It is similar to the concept of "symmetrization" of scalar random variables, in the sense that a random variable sampled from $\overline \pi$ has the same distribution as $Q \theta$ where $Q$ is uniform on $O(d)$ and $\theta$ is (independently) drawn from $\pi$.

Some concrete questions are: is it a surjection to the family of rotationally invariant probability measures on $\Theta$? Is it invertible on its image? What else is known about it?

Comment: Isn’t Lebesgue measure the unique rotation-invariant measure up to scaling? If that’s so, the map $\bar\pi$ should be pretty easy to describe.

Comment: There are other measures, in general, which are rotation invariant, right? For instance, a (truncated) Gaussian with identity covariance.

Comment: I think that’s also Lebesgue?

Comment: I don't think so. For instance a Gaussian truncated to the unit ball places much more mass near the origin than the Lebesgue (i.e., uniform) measure does, no?

Comment: My mistake. I somehow thought you were talking about the unit sphere. But in that case, aren’t measures completely described by the radial measure?

Comment: Doesn't $\bar\pi$ send any rotationally-symmetric measure to itself? If so, it's immediate that $\bar\pi$ is surjective.